# Equality of ordered n-tuples

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

In a *Mathematical Introduction to Logic*, Enderton says it is easy to see (by using induction on $n$ and the basic property of ordered pairs ($\left\langle x,y\right\rangle =\left\langle u,v\right\rangle \iff x=u\land y=v$ )) that (for all $n$) if $\left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right\rangle =\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}\right\rangle$  then $x_{i}=y_{i}$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. I'm having some difficulty doing this

---

Definitions

Enderton defines $\left\langle x\right\rangle:= x$ so the base case $n=1$ is trivial. He also defines $\left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n+1}\right\rangle :=\left\langle \left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right\rangle ,x_{n+1}\right\rangle$.

---

Attempt:

For the induction step, we want to show $\left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right\rangle =\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}\right\rangle \rightarrow \left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n+1}\right\rangle =\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n+1}\right\rangle $

By definition, we have

$\begin{align} \left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n+1}\right\rangle  &=\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n+1}\right\rangle \\
\left\langle \left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right\rangle ,x_{n+1}\right\rangle  &=\left\langle \left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}\right\rangle ,y_{n+1}\right\rangle \end{align}$

but the basic property of ordered pairs is that

$\left\langle x,y\right\rangle =\left\langle u,v\right\rangle \iff x=u\land y=v$

Thus
$x_{n+1}=y_{n+1}$ and $\left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right\rangle =\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}\right\rangle$

So I've proved 
$$ \left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n+1}\right\rangle  =\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n+1}\right\rangle \iff x_{n+1}=y_{n+1} \land \left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right\rangle =\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}\right\rangle$$

the induction hypothesis is $\left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right\rangle =\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}\right\rangle$, but I don't see how to derive the other premise: $x_{n+1}=y_{n+1}$, or make the induction step.

---

Attempt #2
For the induction hypothesis, we assume there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:

$\left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right\rangle =\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}\right\rangle \rightarrow x_{i}=y_{i}(1\leq i\leq n)$

In the induction step, we show that this implies:

$\left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n+1}\right\rangle =\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n+1}\right\rangle \rightarrow x_{i}=y_{i}(1\leq i\leq n+1)$.

Thus for the induction step, we may assume

$\begin{align} \left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n+1}\right\rangle  &=\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n+1}\right\rangle \\
\left\langle \left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right\rangle ,x_{n+1}\right\rangle  &=\left\langle \left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}\right\rangle ,y_{n+1}\right\rangle \end{align}$

but the defining property of ordered pairs is that

$\left\langle x,y\right\rangle =\left\langle u,v\right\rangle \iff x=u\land y=v$.

Thus $x_{n+1}=y_{n+1}$ and $\left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right\rangle =\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}\right\rangle$ . Thus by the induction hypothesis, we have $x_{i}=y_{i}(1\leq i\leq n)$. Since we showed $x_{n+1}=y_{n+1}$, we have $x_{i}=y_{i}(1\leq i\leq n+1)$ which is what we wanted to prove.

Answer (score 3):

Your goal for the "induction step" is the wrong way around. Since $\left<x_1,\ldots\right>=\left<y_1,\ldots\right>$ is a *premise* of the implication you want to prove, the right induction step should go as:

1. Our goal is to show that if $\left<x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}\right> =\left<y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1}\right>$ then all of the $x_i$s and $y_i$ agree.
2. Thus, **assume** $\left<x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}\right> =\left<y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1}\right>$.
3. The induction hypothesis tells us that if $\left<x_1,\ldots,x_n\right> =\left<y_1,\ldots,y_n\right>$ then the first $n$ values agree.
4. Now, if we can show $$\left<x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}\right> =\left<y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1}\right> \to \left<x_1,\ldots,x_n\right> =\left<y_1,\ldots,y_n\right>,$$ then together with (2) that will give us what whe need to apply the induction hypothesis. ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me realize that the source of my confusion was that the induction hypothesis was itself an implication, so the logic of the induction step was $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (C \rightarrow D)$. I've added another attempt. Could you please comment? If everything is good i'll accept this answer.

Comment: And  $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (C \rightarrow D) \equiv [C \land (A \rightarrow B)] \rightarrow D$. In this case, $C$ was $\left\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n+1}\right\rangle =\left\langle y_{1},\ldots,y_{n+1}\right\rangle$ and $A \rightarrow B$ was the induction hypothesis, which explains how those two facts gave us the result.